# Delphi, using numbers in edits

Tags: delphi

I was wondering if there is a component like the 'edit', but just for numbers so I can use the `.value` function in my code.
My textbook says I must make a program, that when the user enters a number and clicks the execute button, the results of the functions must be determined. 
The functions are: Trunc, round, frac, sqr and sqrt.
I have to enter the value into, what looks like an 'edit', but whenever I use the `.value` in my code, it gives me an error saying :`Undeclared identifier: 'value'`. Although it works when I use a 'SpinEdit'.
Forgive me for being really thick, I do have a severe chest and sinus infection with a fairly bad fever, so my mind is somewhere else at the moment.
Thanks!
Oh, and by the way, I have also used the 'MaskEdit' component but it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an edit control there is no property named `Value`, which is what the compiler is telling your. For an edit control the property you need is [`Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.Text). That's a `string` containing the contents of the edit control. You'll need to use `StrToFloat` or `TryStrToFloat` to convert to a real type.

You can use a masked edit if you like, and validate the input on entry. The `TMaskEdit` control derives from `TCustomEdit`, and again the property used for accessing its content is `Text` and of type `string`.

Personally I don't like that because I don't think it gives the clearest feedback to users. It's also hard to write a mask for a general floating point value. Myself, I would validate at the point where the program needs to convert from string to real.

Comment: iAmount := TryStrToFloat(edtInput.value); - That's my current code, but it still gives me the same error

Comment: @link Read my answer more closely. There is no `Value`. That's what the compiler says. It is `Text`.

Comment: Maybe I should just come back to this once I am feeling a bit better, this is far too confusing for me at the moment. Otherwise I'll just use a spinedit for now.

Comment: Don't use a spin edit. Use `TryStrToFloat(edtInput.Text, Value)` and it's all good.

Comment: '[Error] Functions_U.pas(36): There is no overloaded version of 'TryStrToFloat' that can be called with these arguments' I'm going to shoot myself soon :(

Comment: Hmm. Use a spin edit rather than shooting yourself! No, you need an extra parameter. See the docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToFloat  I've updated my previous comment. Your code looks like this: `if TryStrToFloat(edtInput.Text, Value) then ...` where `Value` is a real variable to hold the result of a successful conversion.

Comment: I used: iAmount := StrToInt(edtInput.Text); Looks like its working now. Thanks for your help David!

Comment: Well, if you only want integers then you may as well use a spin edit right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you asked if there is an edit like component for that, I use [TMS AdvEdit](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advedit.asp). It does a very decent job handling integers and floats. If you can afford it, it's really useful.

It has `.FloatValue` and `.IntValue` properties for reading and writing the value, and an `EditType` that specifies what kind of input is accepted.